# How to check for empty and not a failure

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I'm querying the postmeta table to see if a url has already been entered, using this statement (where $thisLink is the url I'm checking)

```
  $mypostids = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = 'rssmi_source_link' and meta_value like '%".$thisLink."%'");
```

The problem is that on some servers it appears it's not finding urls that already exist in the database, and I'm becoming convinced that this may be due to the server failing on the query or something like that.

Anyway, I'm not sure how to check for both the url already exist (thus don't process anymore) or there was some sort of failure in completing the query).  right now, I just use:

```
if (empty( $mypostids )){ do stuff}
```

is there a way I could make the condition like if empty AND if not a failure then do stuff?

Comment: What is "not a failure"? I use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) all the time because it returns `false` for all kinds of values. It looks to me like it should work the way you want it too.

Answer (score 2):

You test for a fail by explicitly testing for false:

```
if (null === $mypostids) { /* it failed */ }
```

NB: three equals signs! you want to check for [identical, not just equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

edit: originally said `false`, changed to `null` after looking at get_result() function in source.

Comment: [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) already does that.

Comment: OP wants to know how to differentiate "no rows found" (which is an empty array) from "error" (which is `null` -- got it wrong above). Why is up to them, frankly.

Comment: That is not how I interpret "empty AND if not a failure", but maybe you are right. It isn't quite clear.

Comment: Thanks...I'll try that test for fail along with the empty.